# Index of word within text in R

Tags: r, text, vector, indexing

I have text within a character vector but i am unable to find word's index within character vector,how can i extract it efficiently without going through each word and by adding length of each word using **nchar** and **match**.

```
which("ashish"=="i am ashish and ashish is good")
integer(0)
grep("apple","i am ashish and ashish is good")
integer(0)
grep("apple","It is a apple and apple is tasty")
[1] 1
```

I want indexes of "apple" that is 9,19 within text.Any suggestion for better method,thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gregexp` is the function you're looking for:

```
gregexpr("apple","It is a apple and apple is tasty")
```